# MEAN app api endpoints work, but app endpoints don't

Tags: heroku

I have a MEAN app located at https://stark-plains-64835.herokuapp.com/. When I go to it, I get an 'Internal Server Error' and an error code of 500. If I manually navigate to any of my API endpoints ('/products' or '/products/:id'), I get the expected JSON response. However, if I try any of my app endpoints ('/', '/shop', or '/shop/:id'), I get the same server error. I have tried everything that I can think of to fix this, but I keep getting the same result.

Here's the heroku logs:

2018-10-01T15:20:01.592271+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-10-01T15:20:04.233481+00:00 app[web.1]: > ecommerce-mean-app@0.0.0 start /app
2018-10-01T15:20:04.233483+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2018-10-01T15:20:05.748475+00:00 app[web.1]: Server listening on port 14423...
2018-10-01T15:20:05.863818+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to DB: mongodb://richard:password@ds155577.mlab.com:55577/ecommerce-mean-app
2018-10-01T15:20:06.358783+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-10-01T15:20:08.037030+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-plains-64835.herokuapp.com request_id=433ea581-20b8-483a-ad96-794f055363fa fwd="67.166.19.44" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=500 bytes=436 protocol=https
2018-10-01T15:20:08.035986+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'html'
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036005+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036007+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036009+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036011+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036013+00:00 app[web.1]: at new View (/app/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:81:14)
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036015+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036017+00:00 app[web.1]: at ServerResponse.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036019+00:00 app[web.1]: at app.get (/app/app.js:23:7)
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036021+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036022+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036024+00:00 app[web.1]: at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036025+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036026+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036028+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036030+00:00 app[web.1]: at cors (/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036029+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Richard! What do your logs say when it errors? You can check them with “heroku logs”. Please update your question with the error message from your logs.

Comment: Hi Jon, I've added the heroku logs. Let me know if I need to add any other info or what I can do to get the app deployed correctly. Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was that my server script "app.js" didn't know where to find the static files. After adding `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));`, the app deploys and runs great!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the main issue:

```
01T15:20:08.035986+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'html' 
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036005+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15) 
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036007+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25) 
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036009+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (module.js:597:17) 
2018-10-01T15:20:08.036011+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/module.js:11:18) 2018-10-
```

So you have a dependency issue. I'd double-check your `package.json` and make sure that this package is listed properly for production use.